# EF6 Select all and Set One field

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Is there a way to select all the properties in a collection and set one without verbosly remapping the entire property list?

```
return =
    _input.Where(
            w => w.MaterialNumber.Contains("foo")
                    ).Select(s => new Material.list() { ID = s.ID, MaterialNumber = s.MaterialNumber, orColor = "#303030" }).ToList()
);
```

Looking for something simpler.

```
return =
    _input.Where(
            w => w.MaterialNumber.Contains("foo")
                    ).Select(s => new Material.list() {s, new orColor = "#303030" }).ToList()
);
```

Comment: how is this entity framework question if you are using Regex? Or am I missing something and it is actually transpiled into SQL?

Comment: I can remove the Regex Expression if its making the question difficult to understand.

Comment: You could add a parameterized constructor with your type as the parameter. We don't know what the type of `s` is in your select, changed to type `Foo` here.  `public Material.list(Foo sType) { .. copy properties .. }`  and use like  `s => new Material.list(s) { orColor = .... }`

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned EF 6 but you don't actually use it in the question. Also you mentioned mapping, but are you sure if it is required? If it is possible for other code to use same instance without remapping, just use any approach listed below to set property of the original object

```
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class DTO
    {
        public string Color { get; set; }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var input = Enumerable.Repeat(new DTO(), 10);

            // select statement
            var selectOutput = input.Select(x =>
            {
                x.Color = "#303030";

                return x;
            });

            // ForEach extension
            var listOutput = input.ToList();

            listOutput.ForEach(x => x.Color = "#303030");

            // regular foreach
            foreach (var inputItem in input)
            {
                inputItem.Color = "#303030";
            }
        }
    }
}
```